# pdfMake fillcolor for table column with row

Tags: vue.js, pdfmake

i am generating pdf content dynamically. i wanted color last column of this table in green.
i am new to pdfmake. How to achieve that?

column fill color i have achieved using below. but not getting how to fill cell color of that column.

{
text: `T`,
style: 'tableHeader',
field: ``,
border: [true, true, true, true],
fillColor: '#00ff73'
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follow:

```
     layout: {
        fillColor: function(rowIndex, node, columnIndex) {
          // You can change condition according to your requirements
          return  columnIndex=== yourColumnsArray.length-1 ? 'green' : grey;
        },
       
      }
```